# Why does this init gets dispatched to an internal extension init?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a hard time understanding this intermodule communication. My app consumes 3 modules.

We will call them Module A, Module B and Module C.

Both Module B and Module C consume Module A.

The dependency looks something like this: [image: Dependency]

Let's say I have this `BaseViewController` declared in Module A.

```
open class BaseViewController: UIViewController { }
```

In module B, I have the following declaration:

```
extension BaseViewController {
    internal convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: .moduleA)
    }
}
```

Now from my knowledge, this declaration should only be visible at a module level, not outside the module.

In module C, I have a `BaseViewController` subclass which uses programmatic layout.

```
class MySuperViewController: BaseViewController { }
```

In the same module C, I have a coordinator which initialises this view controller like this:

```
let mySuperVC = MySuperViewController()
```

I call this coordinator method that instantiates this `mySuperVC` from my iOS app where I import all A, B and C modules.

I was expecting that `MySuperViewController()` to call the `UIViewController`'s initialiser, since the convenience init of the `BaseViewController` is declared inside Module B and it is internal, however, the initialiser that is being called is the internal one from Module B, thus making my app crash since it's not finding the nib.

I tried to write an identical convenience init inside Module C, but it calls the same internal init from Module B. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there a difference in behaviour if you add the convenience init inside the declaration of BaseViewController instead of in extension ?

Comment: @Petar No, the one that is called is still the one from Module B.

Comment: I guess if you do `let vc = BaseViewController()` from within module B or C it won't take you to the convenience init ? Also - if you add a dummy parameter to the convenience init are you able to see that initializer from XCode's autocomplete when you try to initialize MySuperViewController from C ?

Comment: @Petar They both take me to the convenience init.

Comment: @Petar I just added a default parameter to the convenience init and it works correctly now, it dispatches to the `UIViewController` init. Also the initialiser with the default parameter was not visible by the XCode's autocomplete. Hmm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/extensions/):

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality.

Your extension is invalid and it is undefined what method will be called. `init()` is an existing method on UIViewController, and so you cannot override it in an extension.

As a practical matter of why this happens, BaseViewController is an Objective-C type. When the module is loaded, this `init` method is attached to it (there isn't one currently; there's just one on its superclass). When a later caller sends the selector "init" to the BaseViewController instance, it will find this method while walking up the hierarchy. At runtime, the system does not know where the method came from. It just gets attached when the module is loaded. This is non-deterministic, which is why overriding methods in extensions is undefined behavior.